# How Modern OpenGL ID's works?

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer

i don't understand how OpenGL ID works. Example:

```
 static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data),      g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Here openGL get positions of array and create one buffer and put position of array in buffer. I understood that. But i don't understand this code below. What exactly this do? From what i a read he create a array of id to buffer, but it seems somewhat abstract.

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
```

In my mind i see this code like this:

[image: How id woks in my mind]

Comment: Actually you re looking for a tutorial or specification. See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) or [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle). Pease read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`glGenBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml) reserves numbers (names) for Buffer Objects. [`glBindBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml) creates the buffer object with the specified number (name) if it does not already exist.
[`glGenVertexArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml) creates respectively reserves numbers (names) that can be used for [Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). [`glBindVertexArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexArray.xhtml) creates the Vertex Array Object with the specified number (name) if it does not already exist.
The Vertex Array Object stores the vertex specification. It stores all information specified by [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml), [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml), etc. for each attribute in a vector separately. When `glVertexAttribPointer` is called, the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER` is associated to the attribute and the number (name) of the object is stored in the state vector of the VAO.

Comment: Hi thanks for you help! I understand it that way, is right now? https://ibb.co/nmMCW9D                                                   glGenBuffers -> create ID buffer                                              glBindBuffer  -> binBuffer on ID                                               glBufferData -> put data on buffer                                                 glGenVertexArrays -> create vertex array id                            glBindVertexArray  -> bind vertex arrey id  glVertexAttribPointer -> send vertex array how interpret buffer data